# How unordered_map<int,int> handles negative elements?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I can assign negative elements as key in map, like `map[-1]=10;` how it handles it in back, what data structure is used for it? I know unordered_map uses hashing internally, how it handles negative elements for hashing? If I use an array for hashing I can't hash negative elements cause array index can't be negative

Comment: That's easy: `static_cast<unsigned int>`

Comment: _How unordered_map<int,int> handles negative elements?_ In short: Like positive elements.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Unordered map is an associative container that contains key-value
>   pairs with unique keys. Search, insertion, and removal of elements
>   have average constant-time complexity.
>
> Internally, the elements are not sorted in any particular order, but
>   organized into buckets. Which bucket an element is placed into depends
>   entirely on the hash of its key. This allows fast access to individual
>   elements, since once the hash is computed, it refers to the exact
>   bucket the element is placed into.

[unordered_map](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) uses hashing for accessing elements. There is no problem in hashing negative integers, or any other type, as long as the hash function is defined.